# RequireJS is not loading modules relative to the baseUrl

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

In the <head> tag

```
<script>
var require = {
    baseUrl: '/dist/js',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-1.11.3'
    }
};
</script>
<script data-main="main.js" src="/dist/js/require.js></script>
```

And in `main.js`:

```
define(["exports", "jquery", "order.js", "search.js"], function (exports, _jquery, _orderJs, _searchJs) {
  "use strict";

  console.log("Hello");
});
```

Now, `main.js` loads just fine, same with jquery. But order.js and search.js is being loaded from the root (`http://example.com/order.js`).
Why is it not loading from the baseUrl?

Comment: should the base URL end in a slash?

Comment: Don't think so, but i tried, and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is `</script>` a copy error, or your bug (first line)?

Comment: It is(was) a copy error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.js` extension from the module names you give to `define` or `require`. If you put the extension yourself, then RequireJS assumes the module name is a literal path and will skip your configuration.

Comment: And what to do in case of having two files: `search.js` and `search.css`?